# How to show a progess of GridFS downloading a file from the MongoDB?

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, gridfs

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow show the progress of reading a file with `gridfs.GridFS()` and pymongo. I could not file a callback I could pass to the `.read()` function.

```
my_db = MongoClient().test
fs = GridFSBucket(my_db)
# get _id of file to read.
file_id = fs.upload_from_stream("huge_test_file", "i carry lots of data!")
grid_out = fs.open_download_stream(file_id)
contents = grid_out.read()
```

Is there some way to actually retrieve the bytes that were already downloaded? Considering, the file may be being 5GB big, I want to give some download status feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 11 months.. but i think a way to do this is:

Make a new endpoint that returns the last chunks 'n' value, then compare this with the file 'chunkSize' value.

```
@app.route('/uploadProgress/<string:fileID>')
def uploadProgress(fileID):
    doc = db.fs.files.find_one({"_id": fileID})
    size = doc['chunkSize']
    n = db.fs.chunks.find( { "files_id": fileID } ).sort([('n', -1)]).limit(1)[0]['n']
    progress = str(n/size)
    return progress
```

Now in javascript you can make a request to check the progress and update the progress bar